# How to Integrate MediaPipe Hand Tracking in a Jetpack Compose Android App?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, mediapipe

I am working on an Android application using Jetpack Compose and I want to integrate MediaPipe's Hand Gesture recognition into my app. I am able to set up MediaPipe in my project and I have the .pbtxt files for the hand tracking graph.

However, I am struggling to figure out where to put the code to start the camera and display the recognized hand landmarks. I'm also unsure how to run the MediaPipe graph on the camera frames and extract the results.

Here is what I have so far:

````
```Kotlin
// Camera setup (in a Composable)
@Composable
fun CameraPreview() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val cameraProviderFuture = remember { ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(context) }
    AndroidView({ context ->
        PreviewView(context).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
        }
    }, update = { view ->
        val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
        // TODO: Setup the rest of the CameraX preview use case
    })
}

// MediaPipe setup
val graphProcessor = ... // TODO: Setup the graph processor
graphProcessor.setGraph("mediapipe/graphs/hand_tracking/hand_tracking_mobile.pbtxt")
graphProcessor.addPacketCallback("hand_landmarks", PacketCallback { packet: Packet ->
    // TODO: Process the hand landmarks
})

// TODO: Start the graph, run it on the camera frames, extract the results

```
````

Could you please guide me on where to put the code to start the camera, run the MediaPipe graph on the camera frames, and display the recognized hand landmarks on the camera preview? Any help would be much appreciated.